# screenslot in the pixijs webgl screenslot problem

Tags: pixi.js

i use screentslot in pixijs webgl
but get base64 image width and height  is not  canvas's width and height
how can i do it

this my code

```
    var app = new PIXI.Application({
        width: 750,
        height: 750,
        transparent: true
    });
    $('body').html(app.view);

 
    const perlin = PIXI.Sprite.from('https://wxserver.knowway.cn//caitongxiaonian/images/4/p4_wrap1_wrap2_4.png');
        app.stage.addChild(perlin)

setTimeout(function(){
       var xss=app.renderer.extract.canvas(app.stage);
     let base64Img = xss.toDataURL('image/png') 
       console.log(base64Img);
},3000)
```

https://codepen.io/a6965921/pen/wvoBQde